# Elasticsearch query excluding the results from another query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

A simplified Elasticsearch index of 'articles' has documents with fields `domain_name` and `tag`, plus some other content.

`tag` is limited to a handful of keyword values, such as `source1`, `source2`, where `tag` can only have a single value in each document. `domain_name` is a single value in each document

I would like to return a set of documents where `tag=source1` that do not include the `domain_name` from another query where `tag=source2`

In two steps this would be something like:

**set to exclude**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "tag" : "source2" } 
  }
}
```

Results would be processed to produce an array of `domain_name` values, one from each returned document.

The second query would then get all items it cares about, then exclude the terms it doesn't (the list of domain names from the previous query).

**query minus set to exclude**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term" : { "tag" : "source1" } 
      },
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "tag": [<array of domain_name values>]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible in a single query, or using aggregates? The indexes and result sets would not be massive, so I'm less worried about performance than convenience.

Bonus question, could this be defined in Kibana directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my case i used programming language(Java) to execute first query and get the result array of document by first query then i stored the ids of query result in array and used this array which contain ids of first query to execute second query 
elastic not support nested query

Comment: I don't think that it is entirely true that ES doesn't support some kinds of nested query. For example, the *terms lookup* allows a list from an attribute in one document to feed a *terms query*: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup . I was hoping that there was some other kind of query, scoring or aggregation that I had missed.

Comment: you can use terms if you have value of field , but in your case your value will be from another separated query result then use it to second query

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it seems to be correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid two calls, please make use of either nested query or (has_child and has_parent) queries.
Refer Elasticsearch [Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html)

Comment: has_child and has_parent will support only if you have stored data with join or nested type of field.